# Deserialize XML Array of Elements

Tags: c#

So, deserializing is working however I have some xml like this:

```
<File>
  <Stuff>stuff</Stuff>
  <Devices>
    <Device Type="1">
      <Number>1</Number>
    </Device>
    <Device Type="2">
      <Number>2</Number>
    </Device>
  </Devices>
</File>
```

When it gets to the array of devices... the first device is the only one that is populated into an object. Here are the classes:

```
            XmlSerializer deserializer;
            XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(CONFIG_PATH, FileMode.Open);
            XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);

            // Details configuration area.
            xRoot.ElementName = "File";
            xRoot.IsNullable = true;
            deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(File), xRoot);
            Configuration = (File)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);

[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "File", IsNullable = true)]
public sealed class File
{
    [XmlElement("Devices")]
    public Devices Devices { get; set; }
}

// <summary>
/// Configuration device elements.
/// </summary>
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Devices", IsNullable = true)]
public sealed class Devices
{
    [XmlElement("Device")]
    public DeviceElements[] DeviceElements { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Configuration Devices.
/// </summary>
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Device", IsNullable = true)]
public sealed class DeviceElements
{
    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Number")]
    public int DeviceNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Again, only the first Device is populated, I've played with XmlArray And XmlArrayItem however neither of them were even giving me the first value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried taking out all the "XmlElement" and "XmlRoot" attributes? I find serialization works best when I leave things alone as much as possible and let the framework sort it out for me.

Comment: It won't even deserialize if I take them out.

Comment: Try this suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534451/xml-deserialization-and-loose-array-items

Comment: Each Device element has to explicitly be called Device. Device could be an unlimited amount of elements within the Devices element. The suggestion above won't work in my case.

Comment: Good luck ! Hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be doing something wrong at another place. Just using the `Devices` part of your XML:

```
  <Devices>
    <Device Type="1">
      <Number>1</Number>
    </Device>
    <Device Type="2">
      <Number>2</Number>
    </Device>
  </Devices>
```

I was able to successfully deserialize a `Devices` class instance with multiple `DeviceElements` children given your classes above using similar code as you used in your last question:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);

XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Devices));
var devicesResult = (Devices)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

**Edit:**

Using the full XML:

```
<File>
  <Stuff>stuff</Stuff>
  <Devices>
    <Device Type="1">
      <Number>1</Number>
    </Device>
    <Device Type="2">
      <Number>2</Number>
    </Device>
  </Devices>
</File>
```

This successfully deserializes for me:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);

XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "File";
xRoot.IsNullable = true;

XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(File), xRoot);
var fileResult = (File)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

On a side note - you probably shouldn't name your class the same as one already in the .NET framework (`System.IO.File`), also in above code example setting the Xml root is not required since you use the same name anyway, just leave this out:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(File));
var fileResult = (File)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: Then maybe my issue is up the ladder, I set the deserializer typeof to a File class with this inside

public sealed class File
{
    [XmlElement("File")]
    public Devices Devices { get; set; }
}

Could this be my issue?

Comment: @bl4kh4k: Hard to say w/o seeing a complete code sample that reproduces the problem - would be good to update the question

Comment: Just updated with the missing class. If you can figure it out your a serializedGod.

Comment: I removed the XmlRootAttribute but it still will only deserialize the first Device out of the array.

Comment: It works, had some elements inside elements that weren't deserializing which apparently keeps it from adding to the array and breaks out. Thanks for your help. Cheers.

Comment: @bl4kh4k what sort of elements?